# How do I define a libpcre regexp for arabic characters?

Tags: php, regex, drupal-6, utf-8, arabic

I need to define a PCRE regexp for certain spam-ish words in Arabic/Persian alphabet to be used in [drupal spam module](http://drupal.org/project/spam). The problem is that the usual PCRE regexp is apparently unable to find patters in Arabic alphabets.

For example, while /bad word/ flags instances of 'bad word', but

```
/کلمه بد/i
```

Is unable to flag 'کلمه بد'.

Comment: Have you tried it with the Unicode flag? `/کلمه بد/iu`

Comment: Well, I tried both /کلمه بد/iu and /کلمه بد/u but none seem to flag the pattern.

Comment: Tim Pietzcker, I think your comment is not helpful. I bet qliq is not running a developer version of Perl (5.13+) where the [`u` *modifier*](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.14.0-RC2/pod/perlre.pod#Character_set_modifiers) ([future permalink](http://p3rl.org/re#Character_set_modifiers)) is actually available. Also, setting it has no effect in the given example - refer to the documentation.

Comment: If you say `use utf8;` in the source unit that contains the Unicode characters, you should be just fine. You shouldn’t need to use the 5.14 `/u` flag, as that would only rarely be needed at most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no problem with that if I use the *`u`* (Unicode) PCRE modifier:

```
$string = 'کلمه بد';

if (preg_match('~\p{Arabic}~u', $string) > 0)
{
    var_dump('contains Arabic characters');

    if (preg_match('~کلمه بد~ui', $string) > 0)
    {
        var_dump('contains spam-ish Arabic characters');
    }
}

string(26) "contains Arabic characters"
string(35) "contains spam-ish Arabic characters"
```

It runs just fine [on IDEOne.com](http://www.ideone.com/0U1gW) too. Be sure to save your files (and convert input data) in (to) UTF-8.

Comment: please see my comment to hobbs answer. in Drupal' spam module API, I am limited to use // syntax, not any code.

Comment: @qliq: Try defining the following regex then: `/کلمه بد/ui`.

Comment: Thanks AlixAxel, apparently /کلمه بد/ui works while /کلمه بد/iu and /کلمه بد/u did not. Please add it as a new answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Literal Unicode text in Perl source will only be recognized properly if the source file has `use utf8;` in it.

You can do `/\x{644}/` and you can do

```
open my $fh, '<:utf8', 'somefile.txt' or die "blah blah";
my $bad_thing = <$fh>;
/$bad_thing/;
```

and either will work without the `utf8` pragma if your data is properly decoded, but if you want to do `/ل/` then you need `use utf8`. Make sense?

Comment: The pertinent documentation explaining the concepts in more detail is linked at http://p3rl.org/UNI.

Comment: hobbs, I can only use /blabla/ not any code in place of regexp (it is going to be used in php's PCRE functions. So not sure how to implement your suggestion for /کلمه بد/